# Issues about using unique_ptr as type of vector (C++)

Tags: c++, vector, attributes, unique-ptr

I‘m trying to understand a C++ code that uses vector which stores `unique_ptr<Base>`, where `Base` is a base class and has a derived class `Derivate`.

When pushing `unique_ptr<Derivate>` into this vector, there is no errors and can correctly call the method of derived class.

But when trying to modify a specific attribute of `Derivate`, there is an error " error: 'class Base' has no member named 'deri_name' ".

The code is as follow:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void test(){
        cout << "this is Base test" << endl;
    }

};

class Derivate :public Base
{
public:
    Derivate(const string& name):deri_name(name){

    }
    virtual void test(){
        cout << "this is Derivate test by " << deri_name << endl;
    }

    string deri_name;
};

int main()
{
    vector<unique_ptr<Base>> vec;
    vec.push_back(make_unique<Derivate>("wayne"));

    vec[0]->test(); // will sprint "this is Derivate test by wayne"

    //vec[0]->deri_name = 'wong';  // will report an error " error: 'class Base' has no member named 'deri_name' "

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried some methods, but there seems no straightforward way to cast `vec[0]` from `unique_ptr<Base>` to `unique_ptr<Derivate>`

could I possibly modify `vec[0]->deri_name` without modifying the type of `vec`?

Comment: Given that a `unique_ptr<Base>` may not actually be managing a `Derivate` (in which case, forcing the compiler to allow you to act as if it is will cause undefined behaviour)  why do you want to do this?     As a rough rule, unless you have a VERY specific reason, a need/desire to do something like this is usually a sign of a broken design, and it is better to fix the design instead of trying to force the compiler to allow you to do this.

Comment: "*there seems no straightforward way to cast `vec[0]` from `unique_ptr<Base>` to `unique_ptr<Derivate>`*" - you can't cast a `unique_ptr<X>` to a `unique_ptr<Y>` when `X != Y` under any circumstance, as they are completely unrelated types. You can, however, move-construct a `unique_ptr<X>` from a `unique_ptr<Y>` if `Y` derives from `X`, and cast a raw `X*` to a raw `Y*` if `Y` derives from `X` or vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vector stores pointers to `Base`, which has no member named `deri_name`. If you are *certain* that `vec[0]` points to a `Derivate` object, you can static-cast:

```
static_cast<Derivate&>(*vec[0]).deri_name = "wong";
```

If you don't know for sure, you can dynamic-cast:

```
if (auto ptr = dynamic_cast<Derivate*>(vec[0].get()))
    ptr->deri_name = "wong";
```

Because this kind of thing is typically a pain, consider making your `Base` class provide virtual methods for operations that derivative classes can opt into. For instance, a `set_name` method that by default does nothing, but the `Derivate` class overrides.

Only you know your requirements, but it's often worth considering ways to avoid polluting code with typecasts, if you can cleanly implement something without it.